# Is it possible to do mirror of uiwebview with chromecast?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, google-cast, chromecast

Is it possible to do mirror of uiwebview with Chromecast? With chrome browser is very simple, but a need to do this from iOS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently supported.

Comment: Any idea when/or if this will be supported?

Comment: @Naddaf i don't have Audio/Video to play. I just need to mirroring the app screen to external display (apple TV or supported). Is it possible with this cast SDK ?